# Get the difference between two datetime fields in days in Python

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to get the difference between 2 DateField Objects in my python code and thereafter perform calculation based on the difference.
I am using flask for this project and so far have the following code.
Views:

```
@admin.route('/approve/loan_payment/<id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def approve_loan_payment(id):
    if not current_user.is_admin:
        abort(403)
    loan = Loan.query.filter_by(id=id).first()
    if loan is None:
       abort(404)
    else:
       form = ApproveLoanPayment()
        if current_user.is_admin and form.validate_on_submit():
            loan.user.username = form.username.data
            loan.loan_amt = form.loan_amt.data
            loan.my_funds = form.my_funds.data
            loan.approved_on = form.approved_on.data
            loan.repaid_on = form.repaid_on.data
            loan.period = abs((loan.repaid_on - loan.approved_on).days)
loan.period = abs((loan.repaid_on - loan.approved_on).days)
        if loan.period == 'More than 7 days' or \
                loan.period == 'more than 7 days':
            if loan.maximum_charge > loan.my_funds:
                loan.balance = loan.maximum_charge - loan.my_funds
            else:
                loan.balance = loan.my_funds - loan.maximum_charge
                loan.extra = loan.balance
        if loan.period == 'Less than 7 days' or \
                loan.period == 'less than 7 days':
            if loan.minimum_charge > loan.my_funds:
                loan.balance = loan.minimum_charge - loan.my_funds
            else:
                loan.balance = loan.my_funds - loan.minimum_charge
                loan.extra = loan.balance
        loan.confirm_payment = True
        db.session.add(loan)
        db.session.commit()
        if loan.extra >= 0 or loan.balance == 0:
            loan.is_repaid_in_full = True
            loan.user.is_owing = False
            flash("The Loan has been repaid in full")
        if loan.balance > 0:
            loan.is_repaid_in_full = False
            loan.user.is_owing = True
            if loan.maximum_charge > loan.my_funds:
                updated_balance = loan.balance
                loan.maximum_charge = updated_balance
            elif loan.minimum_charge > loan.my_funds:
                updated_balance = loan.balance
                loan.minimum_charge = updated_balance

            flash("Loan payment approved."
                  "Loan balance is %s" % loan.balance)
            flash("The Loan has not yet been repaid in full")
        db.session.add(loan)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('The loan has been repaid')
        return redirect(url_for('admin.view_all_loans'))
    form.username.data = loan.user.username
    form.loan_amt.data = loan.loan_amt
    form.my_funds.data = loan.my_funds
    form.approved_on.data = loan.approved_on

    return render_template('admin/approve-loan-payment.html',
                           form=form, loan=loan)
```

However this displays 'None' as the result.

The form for this implementation is :

```
class ApproveLoanPayment(Form):
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[
    Required(), Length(1, 64), Regexp('^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_.]*$', 0,
                                      'Usernames must have only letters, '
                                      'numbers, dots or underscores')])
    loan_amt = FloatField('Borrowed Amount')
    approved_on = DateField('Date Approved')
    repaid_on = DateField('Date Repaid', default=datetime.utcnow)
    period = IntegerField('Period Taken')
    my_funds = FloatField('Amount Paid')
    submit = SubmitField('Approve Loan')
```

Kindly highlight what I am not doing right.

Comment: Can you correctly format the question ? The code is unreadable

Comment: I just did. Have a look at it now.

Comment: What is your function call that displays None? Can you provide a minimal working example? This would make things much easier to understand.

Comment: There is the full code.

Answer (score 0):

```
if loan.period == 'Less than 7 days' or \
            loan.period == 'less than 7 days':
```

You are comparing an integer against a string, that will never be `True`. Guess this was pseudo code at some point and you forgot to change these bits for something that makes sense. Also, I'm guessing you don't want to do the same comparison on both sides of the `or` operator.

```
if loan.period < 7:
```

You did the same with the 'more than 7 days' part.

Another quick guess of mine is that what's breaking your code is that none of these conditionals ever pass and a minimum amount of code that should always be executed is never executed.